# Are values defined in prototype shared?

Tags: javascript

If defining a member in the prototype shares a member across all instances of an object, does changing the value of that member change it for all objects too?

```
var A = function() {};
A.prototype.value = 1;
A.prototype.getValue = function() {
  return this.value;
};

var B = function() {};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var a = new A();
document.writeln("a constructor is A = " + (a.constructor === A) + "<br>");
document.writeln("a.value = " + a.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("a.getValue() = " + a.getValue() + "<br>");
a.value += 1;
document.writeln("a.value = " + a.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("a.getValue() = " + a.getValue() + "<br>");

var b = new B();
document.writeln("b constructor is B = " + (b.constructor === B) + "<br>");
document.writeln("b.value = " + b.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("b.getValue() = " + b.getValue() + "<br>");
b.value += 1;
document.writeln("b.value = " + b.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("b.getValue() = " + b.getValue() + "<br>");

var bb = new B();
document.writeln("bb constructor is B = " + (bb.constructor === B) + "<br>");
document.writeln("bb.value = " + bb.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("bb.getValue() = " + bb.getValue() + "<br>");
bb.value += 1;
document.writeln("bb.value = " + bb.value + "<br>");
document.writeln("bb.getValue() = " + bb.getValue() + "<br>");
```

The result I get is:

```
a constructor is A = true
a.value = 1
a.getValue() = 1
a.value = 2
a.getValue() = 2

b constructor is B = true
b.value = 1
b.getValue() = 1
b.value = 2
b.getValue() = 2

bb constructor is B = true
bb.value = 1
bb.getValue() = 1
bb.value = 2
bb.getValue() = 2
```

Here's a plunk I've been using to experiment with this. http://plnkr.co/edit/znckausaYi9cQ2glJg1A

If value is in the prototype, why do b and bb seem to have separate instances of value?  I expected the result for bb would look like this:

```
bb constructor is B = true
bb.value = 2
bb.getValue() = 2
bb.value = 3
bb.getValue() = 3
```

Questions:

- Why is this behaving this way?
- Is there a way to verify the location of a member of the prototype?
- Is there a tool that I can use to prove that members are shared across instances vs. a member per instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a value returns the nearest value in the chain. Setting a value sets it on the current object, and the prototype chain is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`a.value` is not a reference to `A.prototype.value`.

You can for instance also do:

```
a.getValue = function () { return 2; }
```

This doesn't change the `getValue` functions for other instance of `A`, or even the prototype that `A` defines.

---

What you're doing is similar to:

```
class A {
    var value = 1;
    function getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
var a = new A();
a.value += 1;
```

I think you're confused with doing:

```
A.value += 1; // note this can not be done in any classical language that I know
```

In JS you would do:

```
A.prototype.value += 1;
```

This does not affect `a`, just new instances of `A` created after this point.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object with new a new instance is created which does not correlate to the previous created object. They only share the same constructor function.

```
var A = function() {};
A.prototype.value = "a value";


var B = function() {};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

console.log(a.value); // a value
console.log(b.value); // a value

a.value = "new a value";

console.log(a.value); // a new value
console.log(b.value); // a value

b.value = "new b value";

console.log(a.value); // new a value
console.log(b.value); // new b value
```